# Python subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['where', 'cl']' returned non-zero exit status.When developing cuda extension on pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, subprocess

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Master-TBSI/CODE/neurvps-master/neurvps-master/eval.py", line 190, in <module>
main()
File "D:/Master-TBSI/CODE/neurvps-master/neurvps-master/eval.py", line 88, in main
model = neurvps.models.VanishingNet(
File "D:\Master-TBSI\CODE\neurvps-master\neurvps-master\neurvps\models\vanishing_net.py", line 23, in __init__
self.anet = ApolloniusNet(output_stride, upsample_scale)
File "D:\Master-TBSI\CODE\neurvps-master\neurvps-master\neurvps\models\vanishing_net.py", line 95, in __init__
self.conv1 = ConicConv(32, 64)
File "D:\Master-TBSI\CODE\neurvps-master\neurvps-master\neurvps\models\conic.py", line 12, in __init__
self.deform_conv = DeformConv(
File "D:\Master-TBSI\CODE\neurvps-master\neurvps-master\neurvps\models\deformable.py", line 132, in __init__
DCN = load_cpp_ext("DCN")
File "D:\Master-TBSI\CODE\neurvps-master\neurvps-master\neurvps\models\deformable.py", line 24, in load_cpp_ext
ext = load(
File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1079, in load
return _jit_compile(
File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1292, in _jit_compile
_write_ninja_file_and_build_library(
File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1391, in _write_ninja_file_and_build_library
_write_ninja_file_to_build_library(
File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1823, in _write_ninja_file_to_build_library
_write_ninja_file(
File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1947, in _write_ninja_file
cl_paths = subprocess.check_output(['where',
File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['where', 'cl']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I've met the error when using cpp_extension to implement DeformConv.I don't understand the meaning of the error message,and the code that leads to failure is below.

```
`if library_target is not None:
    link_rule = ['rule link']
    if IS_WINDOWS:
        cl_paths = subprocess.check_output(['where',
                                            'cl']).decode().split('\r\n')`
```

There is something wrong in the function subprocess.check_output() and it has been bothering me for days. Please help me.

Comment: That build system is clearly looking for the Visual Studio C++ compiler and not finding it

Comment: Its running the command "where cl", looking for `cl.exe` as the C compiler. If you run `where cl` on the command line, it likely won't find it either. Do you have a C compiler installed?

Comment: Of course. I've installed Visual Studio and I can run c++ files on it. Maybe the Pycharm couldn't find it? What can I do about it?

Comment: So you are saying that you can open a command window, just type `cl`, and it runs? If not you don't have your environment correctly configured

Comment: Thanks! I've figured it out. Well, It's just the problem that cl.exe is not correctly configured in the environment. Confusingly, I added the cl.exe of x64 version but it didn't work, then I added the x86 version and it runs, but my system is x64.

Answer (score 1):

I can execute cl from the console, having updated the system path,
but I still have a similar problem, arising from calling torch\utils\cpp_extension.py  om splatting.

```
cl_paths = subprocess.check_output(['where',
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['where', 'cl']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```